# How do I draw a 3D surface in Maxima using an equation?

Tags: plot, graph, drawing, surface, maxima

My assignment is to draw a 3D surface in Maxima using this equation:

> 4*x^2 - y^2 + 8*z^2 = 16

However, I'm simply not sure how to do that with plot3d. Or is there something else I'm supposed to use? Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, it is done like this:

```
hc:x^2+y^2+z^2=9;
draw3d(enhanced3d=true,implicit(hc,x,-5,5,y,-5,5,z,-5,5));
```